# How to discretize data (SIFT features)?

Tags: python-2.7, sift, discretization

My input data looks like

[1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,24,3,0,0,0......]

These are SIFT features for images and they are 128 dimensions for each sample likewise I have about 100,000 samples each with 128 dimensions. I want to discretize these features. Is there any easy python packages which can be used to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you heard of opencv?

Comment: I have but haven't made use of it. I forgot to perform discretization. Without discretization, I performed KMeans with scikit. I haven't used open cv at all. Any suggestions?